# Showing that $x^n+x+3$ is irreducible

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

How do you show that $x^n+x+3$ is irreducible for all $n \ge 2$?

Comment: I think rational root theorem and primality of $3$ might help.

Comment: Rational root theorem helps to show polynomials do not have a linear divisor, but not that they have no polynomial divisors. @PrasunBiswas

Comment: Ah, then I have no idea for the proof. :P @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Irreducible over the integers, or irreducible over the real numbers?

Comment: @user142671 Are you in the same class(room of test) with SamJ ?